# Facebook like box not appearing on mobile phones

Tags: facebook, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I've got a site that has a FB Like-box in an iframe (code attached) the iframe works nicely on PCs, laptops, and android tablets but the contents of the iframe doesn't appear on a mobile device (tried it on Nokia Lumia 610 and 625, and an iPhone 4s), yet it DOES appear on mobile devices emulated on mobiletest.me (not sure how reliable the result of that gizmo can be). I've cleared the caches, neither age not geo are an issue as the content appears on other devices, I haven't monkied around wi the code - so why doesn't it work on phones?

```
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 column">
                <div class="fb" id="News">
                    <b class="pink" style="font-size: x-large; line-height: 45px;">We've been busy...
                    </b>
                    <br />
                    <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FABCFencingltd&amp;width&amp;height=395&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;stream=true"
                        height="395" width="100%" seamless="seamless"></iframe>
                </div>
                <br />
            </div>
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2014/10/02/mobilelike/. Also, not related, but your use of the Bootstrap grid is redundant. Full width columns need no column class and if you did, you would only need col-sm-12.

Comment: Christina - thanks for the heads up re bootstrap. As for the link, this doesn't explain why the contents of the FB-Likebox don't appear on a mobile phone.

Comment: Try logging in to Facebook and then visiting the page with the like box. If you're not logged in, I don't think it will show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer, and it's simple:

Remove the http: from the beginning of the Facebook address.

Answer (score 0):

Take note that emulators such as http://mobiletest.me/ do NOT exactly emulate how it would show on different gadgets. These kinds of websites cannot replicate the same settings or operating system as what a particular gadget uses.

Native simulators are more accurate, for example, the iphone simulator of xcode in OS X. Because it shows exactly how it would appear in an iphone. It uses the same settings and operating system an iphone/ipad uses.

In mobile phones, most often than not, you will have to login before you see that like box. I think it's because it would be a hassle for users to see a like button for facebook when they're not logged in.

Comment: Hi, I've tried it logged in, but with no result, still a blank box.

Comment: Can you give a fiddle or a sample page where this is happening? We can't really help much without those.

Comment: The code for the iframe is given, the issue is that it doesn't work on a mobile phone. So place the code on a page and test that page on a mobile.

Comment: Well, as someone who needs help, you have to set up some page where we could view your problem. You only gave html and who knows what css and js you have that would cause conflict to your iframe.